# How to buffer audio in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I need to learn how to buffer audio stream from a remote server in Blackberry.
There is a sample buffered playback app with Blackberry api but can you tell what url may I use to test the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any audio file (i.e. mp3) served up by a webserver.  So either copy an mp3 file onto your own webserver or find a link to an mp3 file out on the internet.